# How to generate Sequelize models from migrations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I created models and migrations with the command:

`npx sequelize-cli model:generate --name User --attributes firstName:string,lastName:string,email:string`

But after that I changed a lot of data in the migrations as with the commands line I can't (or don't know how to) give options like `allowNull` and `primaryKey`. But the thing is that I have 29 tables some of which have upto 55 columns and I don't want to write the same changes in the models manually. Is there any script of cli tool to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sequelize-auto](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto) to generate models from tables. However, if you are looking a way to automatically update your models from migrations, there are some issues on repo of sequelize but don't think they have implemented it yet.